# Is Sparkfun's MicroView OLED Arduino module a shield?

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, display

I'm getting confused by the Arduino terminologies:  shield, breakout, module.

Is this MicroView an Arduino compatible shield that will plug into Arduino's or Adafruit's Uno?

Comment: From the [project page](https://github.com/sparkfun/MicroView): *The MicroView is a chip-sized Arduino with a built-in OLED.*

Comment: BTW, it started as a [kickstarter project](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1516846343/microview-chip-sized-arduino-with-built-in-oled-di).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MicroView is not an Arduino shield, so you can't plug that into any Arduino. Arduino Uno and MicroView are developed based on Atmega328 controller. So it is 100% code compatible with Arduino Uno, means the code that runs on an Arduino Uno will also be able to run on the MicroView.

Comment: Can shields plug into the MicroView?

Comment: I would say no because not all the Arduino Uno pins are exposed on the Arduino MicroView.  The MicroView only has 16 pins.  However, if you take the time to find out if the pins used for a particular shield are exposed on an Arduino MicroView and you create an adapter as the pins are likely in different physical locations, then you might get the Arduino MicroView to work with an Arduino Uno shield.

Comment: No,  you can't plug in Arduino shields to MicroView. Pin arrangements of Microview  and Arduino shields are different so it is not possible.